# SoundManager2 doesn't play on android

Tags: soundmanager2

I have implemented in a page to play a sound if some criteria are fired inside a polling cycle of 3 seconds as you can see here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    soundManager.setup({
        url: '/js/soundmanager2.swf',
        debugMode: true
    });
});


function playMe() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        url: '/images/woop_woop.mp3',
        onload: function() {
           console.log('start playing...');
           soundManager._writeDebug(this.id + ' loaded');
           this.play();
        }
    }).load();
}


function NewReadyData()
(
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./getData.php?xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {              
                if (sound_notify) {                                     
                    executeAsync(function() {
                        playMe();
                    });                                     
                }                                   
                if ( window.navigator && window.navigator.vibrate && buzz_notify )
                        window.navigator.vibrate(2000);
            } 
        }
    }); 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    setTimeout('NewReadyData', 3000);
}

setTimeout('NewReadyData', 3000);
```

The matter is on Window Desktop it works and it plays that little mp3 but on Android it doesn't play sound. Is there a way to force playing? like calling an ajax so it would play like in independent event of playing when occurs?...

Thanks 
Cheers, 
Luigi

Comment: It is possible that Android only accepts actions like this (playing music on the device) with an action from the user (like a click on an object).

Comment: You realize that Flash on android is basically non-existent? It's discontinued and was never installed on many devices even when it was available. Use HTML5 audio if you have to. If you're targeting mobile, you should NEVER have used flash in the first place.

Comment: @Anton is correct. The issue is that mobile devices require direct, physical, and **synchronous** interaction from the user to begin playback of audio/video.

Comment: @MarcB SoundManager covers this, it uses HTML5 if possible, otherwise Flash. But Android has a "security feature" so a website can't just start playing music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out myself the solution...

I thought I couldn't use  tag but after discovering to enable that flag about requisite  for multimedia reproduction so now I could play  by code.

Thanks everyone anyway! :)
Cheers
Luigi